# Update Display Order Column for Multiple Records in One Statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am building a C#/ASP.NET application that calls a stored procedure to update the database.

I have a table in SQL Server with a column to control the Display Sort Order on output windows / print sheets.

```
[ProductID] [ProductName] [ProductDescription] [ProductSortOrder]
```

I am trying to update all Products (in this case) at one time. I am ONLY updating the Sort Order column in this call but want to avoid hitting the database one time for each product.

I was able to get it working by passing the Product ID to the stored procedure, but wondered about passing a list somehow.

```
UPDATE Products SET ProductSortOrder = 2 WHERE ProductID = 1
```

I'd like to hit the database once and do the processing there to parse the list and update the records based on the value of the list. I'd pass something like `[ProductID1]|[SortOrderValue1],[ProductID2]|[SortOrderValue2]` and split it by `,` then loop through and split each of those by `|` and pass that to the update statement.

I am not sure if this is possible or how to do it in SQL Server.

Comment: You can pass a table variable into a stored procedure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017. You can then do your insert in one statement

Comment: @ChrisWedgwood Got this to work and it's slick! Thanks for the comment & reference link. If you want to reformat as an answer, I will mark as selected answer.

Comment: Done Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a table variable into a stored procedure

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017ew=sql-server-2017).

You can then do your insert in one statement